# How do I replace all fragments of text written in uppercase with lowercase applying a particular style in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, text-formatting, libreoffice-writer

I've received a paper written in a plain text editor and I am to re-format it into a proper quality document. The original documents uses UPPERCASE to emphasize on particular elements of a sentence (one or more contiguous words). I'd like to change all these parts into lowercase italics. How can this possibly be achieved without finding every particular fragment, selecting it and doing the job manually?

Done some googling I've found a number of regex-based recipes for finding all uppercase words but not a single one worked. Some leave me with lowercase parts of words beginning with a capital letter selected, some don't work at all.

The best tool I have found so far after some experimenting is

```
[:upper:]{3,}
```

It would find all uppercase words longer than 3 letters so at least I don't have to rely on my eyes looking for them. But it still only finds to find the words, I still end up selecting contiguous phrases and formatting them manually.

Comment: `Format -> Text -> Sentence Case`? Of course, you would then need to go over the text to recap acronyms and mid-sentence `"I"`s

Comment: Install https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer It can most likely do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer

First define a character style called 'italic'. Then use <kbd>Edit > Alt. Find & Replace</kbd> with these parameters:

Search: [:upper:]{3,}

Replace:
\A{CharStyleName=italic}&

[X] Match case

[X] Regular expressions